If Cells is empty then skip else copy and paste
I have this code that i wish it could filter column K and M.
If after filtering there are values, then vba will copy all cells visible to another sheet.
The problem with this code is that: if after filtering column K & M, and there are no values. Then VBA gives error no cells we found.
Any idea what's wrong with this code?
Thank you in advance
    Function GetTheLastRow(sheetName As String) As Long
        'Function untuk mendapatkan row terakhir dalam sheet
        Dim sheetTarget As Worksheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        
        Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set sheetTarget = wb.Sheets("Absent")
        lastRow = sheetTarget.Cells(sheetTarget.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        GetTheLastRow = lastRow
    End Function
    Sub filterdata()
    Dim sourceSheet As String, targetSheet As String
    Dim lastRowSourceSheet As Long
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    sourceSheet = "Absent"
    lastRowSourceSheet = GetTheLastRow(sourceSheet)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cek As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Absent")

    For Each cek In Range("A1:A" & lastRowSourceSheet)
    Sheet2.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="Marie"
    Sheet2.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Sheet1.Range("B1").Value

    If cek.Value = 0 Then
    Else
        Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("D2:D" & lastRowSourceSheet).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        wb.Sheets("Marie").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
     
        Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("P2:P" & lastRowSourceSheet).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        wb.Sheets("Marie").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End If

    Sheet2.ShowAllData
    Sheet2.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="VONNY"
    Sheet2.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Sheet1.Range("B1").Value

    If cek.Value = 0 Then
    Else
        Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("D2:D" & lastRowSourceSheet).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        wb.Sheets("Vonny").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        
        Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("P2:P" & lastRowSourceSheet).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        wb.Sheets("Vonny").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End If
    Exit For
    Next

    End Sub



Could you describe in a few words what is happening on which sheet? Are Sheet2 and Sheet(sourceSheet) the same? On which sheet is cek located, on Sheet1?

You need to check if there any filtered rows worth copying before copying. Here is an example. Amend this as per your requirement.I have commented it, but if you still have any issue understanding it, simply ask.
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rngToFilter As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long

    With Sheet2
        '~~> Check if sheet 2 has anything
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Remove any preexisting filter
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            
            '~~> Find Last row
            ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=.Range("A1"), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
            
            '~~> Find last Column
            lCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=.Range("A1"), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column
            
            '~~> Identify the range which needs to be filtered
            Set rngToFilter = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))
            
            '~~> Apply filter
            With rngToFilter
                .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="Marie"
                .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Sheet1.Range("B1").Value
                
                '~~> This is your filtered range
                Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            End With
    
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
    End With
    
    '~~> Check if there is a filtered range
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Check if the filtered change is not the first blank row
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Nothing filtered"
        Else
            MsgBox rng.Address
            '~~> This is where you copy
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing filtered"
    End If
End Sub


I've tried your code and its true the message box has shown that "nothing filtered"

The msgbox is just to show you how it works. In the actual code, you do not use the msgbox. if there are any filtered rows, it will get copied else nothing should happen :)

In this sample code there is a table in Range("A1:E9") with header.
Apply this to your code.
If the visible cells count is 0 in the range, an error is generated, which is captured with the Err object.
Sub filtdoub()

Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, "D"
Range("A1").AutoFilter 3, "N"
On Error Resume Next
fff = Range("A2:E9").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
If Err <> 0 Then
    'Code if no rows visible
    MsgBox "No visible rows!"
    Range("A1").AutoFilter
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
Else
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' the code you want to do with visible rows
    MsgBox "Do the code"
End If

Range("A1").AutoFilter
End Sub


what does on error go to 0 do?

Cancel any error handling in the routine. Verbose and StackOverflow
